# Отступы и расположение в html, css

Tags: html, css

Как можно по горизонтали расположить  три фотографии с затемненными полосками содержащими ссылки (с селектором `.photo-title`),  при этом дать промежуток между первой и второй, второй и третьей фотографией? `border-spacing` не подходит так как дает промежуток не только по внутренним отступам но и по внешним, а мне надо по внутренним.

```css
.photo { 
  position:relative; margin-top: 10px;
}
.photo-title {
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  height:35px;
  background:#000;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
  width:332px;
  font-size:1em;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <a href=""><img  src="img/img7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <div class="photo-title">
    <p><a href="">Продукт компании</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <a href=""><img  src="img/img8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <div class="photo-title">
    <p><a href="">Наши Услуги</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <a href=""><img src="img/img9.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <div class="photo-title">
    <p><a href="">Информация о нас</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.photo {
    float: left;/*блоки с фотографиями будут обтекать друг друга слева*/
}
.photo+.photo {
    margin-left: 10px;/*ваш отступ между ними, начиная со второго элемента*/
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое вам! Все получилось!